# Contents of EFS-backed volume vary depending on the container reading it

Tags: docker-compose, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

Why do the contents of my EFS-backed volume vary depending on the container reading it?

I'm seeing divergent, EFS-related behavior depending on whether I run two processes in a single container or each in their own containers.
I'm using the [Docker Compose ECS integration](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/) to launch the containers on Fargate.

The two processes are Database and Verifier.
Verifier directly inspects the on-disk storage of Database.
For this reason they share a volume, and the natural `docker-compose.yml` looks like this (simplifying):

```
services:
  database:
    image: database
    volumes:
      - database-state:/database-state
  verifier:
    image: verifier
    volumes:
      - database-state:/database-state
    depends_on:
      - database
volumes:
  database-state: {}
```

However, if I launch in this configuration the volume `database-state` is often in an inconsistent state when read by Verifier, causing it to error.

OTOH, if I combine the services so both Database and Verifier run in the same container there are no consistency issues:

```
services:
  database-and-verifier:
    image: database-and-verifier
    volumes:
      - database-state:/database-state
volumes:
  database-state: {}
```

Note that in both cases the database state is stored in `database-state`. This issue doesn't appear if I run locally, so it is specific to Fargate / EFS.

Any ideas what's going on and how to fix it?
This feels to me like a write-caching issue, but I doubt EFS would have such a basic problem.
It also feels like it could be a permissions issue, where key files are somehow hid from Verfier.

Thanks!

Comment: "if I launch in this configuration the volume database-state is often in an inconsistent state when read by Verifier" Can you define what "inconsistent state" means? Provide more details about the actual issue please?

Comment: Consistency is a notion defined by the database. "Inconsistent" means the expected files aren't there, can't be read, or don't have the expected contents. The interesting thing is the files in `database-state` are consistent when viewed from the container running the database and inconsistent when viewed from the other container.

Comment: You're still being a bit vague. Are all the files not there? Some of the files? It sounds like perhaps your verifier image is starting up before the database has fully started, so all the files haven't been created yet.

Comment: I just ended up using ECS on EC2, where I can manually control the storage (and it works without issue).